# What is the mechanism of this reaction?

Tags: synthesis, organometallic-compounds

[image]

I've been stuck with this for some time. I just don't see it. As the reactant is Pd(0), I think oxidative addition will happen to the bromine. Then I would say an insertion reaction happens. However this would form a 7-membered ring which isn't as stable as a 5-or 6-membered ring and isn't even in the final product.

Then I tried complexating it with the double bond next to the ether. However I don't see what use the Pd could have from there. Maybe deprotonate the alpha-carbon which would give a hapto-3 complexation? But what next, I wouldn't know. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nicco: Of course you can't "see it". If you were given the correct structure, the solution to your post would be straightforward. There should be a double bond in the lactam ring as shown in compound **1**. The reaction is conducted in acetonitrile (bp. 82<sup>o</sup>C) at reflux. These conditions allow for a Claisen rearrangement to occur to form  ketolactam **2**. Subsequent oxidative addition of palladium(0) [ligands ignored] to the C-Br bond creates the Pd(II) species **3** which adds to the double bond to afford cyclized species **4**. Reductive elimination of Pd(0) regenerates the catalyst as alkene **5** is formed. The role of $\ce{Et3N}$ is to neutralize HBr that is formed. **Addendum:** Just found the original paper: https://doi.org/10.1016/0040-4039(94)88380-7
[image]